# Sprite kit how to fix moving the camera?

Tags: camera, sprite-kit

I tried to bind the camera on my player, with this code:

```
-(void)didSimulatePhysics {
    [self centerOnNode: player];
}

-(void)centerOnNode: (SKNode *) node {
    CGPoint cameraPositionInScene = [node.scene convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];
node.parent.position = CGPointMake(node.parent.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x, node.parent.position.y - camerapositionInScene.y);
}
```

but nothing happens except of getting output like this:

```
Setting the position of a SKScene has no effect.
2014-03-22 16:55:35.604 Jelly Jumper [5801:90b] SKScene:
Setting the position of a SKScene has no effect.
2014-03-22 16:55:35.753 Jelly Jumper [5801:90b] SKScene:
Setting the position of a SKScene has no effect.
2014-03-22 16:55:35.907 Jelly Jumper [5801:90b] SKScene:
```

Comment: The camera node needs to be a child of the node it is following (player). So the problem here is that node.parent points to the scene rather than the player.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a node that holds everything but for player and user interface in it.

For example, call it worldNode. Add it as child to scene and everything on screen but for player and ui to it. Add player and ui as children to your scene directly.

Now when you need to move the player, move worldNode instead. You can calculate the amount you need to move player in update method and apply negative of this to world node. This way it will work as you want.